# multiple filters, one onChange function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My structure:

```
index.js
--> Filters
--> {list}
```

Filters contains multiple input elements that set the state in index.js via props.
list displays as you guessed it, a list of elements. I now want to filter this list based on the values returned by the filters. Pretty standard I think and found on millions of sites.

The issue is that I want to make the input onChange function reusable. With only one input in the Filters component I had this (shortened):

```
<input
   value={this.state.anySearch}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
/>

handleChange = event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ anySearch: value });
};
```

With multiple inputs I tried this, aka reusable for any input:

```
handleChange = name => event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ name: value });
};

onChange={this.handleChange("anySearch")}
```

But this doesn't work anymore. State now shows only one letter at a time when console logged.

What is best practice to filter according to multiple different criteria à la [kayak](https://kayak.com), and how do I rewrite the handleChange function without pushing each letter into an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange = name => event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ name: value });
};
```

your idea of returning a function is correct, you just have an error when setting the state

```
this.setState({ name: value });
```

change it to

```
this.setState({ [name]: value });
```

Regarding the second question, you can simply iterate over your array and filter out the objects that match that specific criteria, to avoid unnecessary overhead you can implement a caching mechanism that keep track of the searches the user has already done.

something like this:

```
function filter(criteria) {
  if(cache[criteria]) {
    return cache[criteria];
  }

  cache[criteria] = myArray.filter(elem => elem.criteria === criteria);
  return cache[criteria];
}
```

Comment: easy, that's it. Can you comment on the other part of the question? How would you implement multiple state values all filtering one array of objects ?